# read some details like name, email, mobile etc from Resume.docx

Tags: php, docx

I try to get some details from Resume.docx

But i have no idea what to do

I tried following things

1)

```
require( "class.filetotext.php" );
$docObj = new Filetotext( "Basic Sample Resume.docx" );
$return = $docObj -> convertToText();
echo $return;
```

2)

```
<?php
function read_file_docx($filename){

    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';


    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;

    $zip = zip_open($filename);

    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;

        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;


        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));


        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }// end while

    zip_close($zip);

    //echo $content;
    //echo "<hr>";
    //file_put_contents('1.xml', $content);

    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
$filename = "Resume.docx";// or /var/www/html/file.docx
```

But it returns in string format how i get details like name, email ,mobile etc

using `php` or `any other things`

**output:**

> ResumeName : xxx xxxEmail :
>   xxx@yahoo.comMobile No . : xxxxxxxxx0

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord try that to parse your xml document properly. Then all information should be properly put in objects. Then use var_dump to analyze output.

Comment: how its use @Tschallacka

Comment: ... read the manual, analyze the examples...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve What are you trying to parse?

Comment: details like email,name , mobile etc from resume

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have the content of the docx stored in you variable
Now you would have to "search" in it using functions like [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php), etc.

If you provide the resulting string may be I can help more.

Anyway, the content of the docx must have some kind of structure in its data to manipulate consistently the content.

Of course a different input file as csv would be very easier to read.